# How to refresh select2 options after dynamic options creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, simple-form

I have a multiple select box with dynamic option creation enabled. After each new option, I send an ajax request and add that option to the DB.

```
$('.skill').on('select2:select',function(e) {
  saveNewItem($(this), 'skill'); //this just save the data iin the DB using Ajax request
}
```

and this works fine. But If I try to add the second new item, it replaces the earlier selected item and as a result only one new option could be selected at a time.

What should I do to add multiple new options to the DB given that each time a new item is added to the dropdown, I have to send the ajax request to be saved in the DB?

Thanks in advance!

```
function saveNewItem($this, element){
  var selTitle = $this.find('option:last-child').val();
  var elem = $this.find('option:last-child');

  if(isNaN(parseInt(selTitle))){
    $.ajax({
      url: "/save_new_"+element,
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data:{title: selTitle},
      success:function(data){
        elem.val(data);
      }
   });
 }
```

}

Comment: depends on implementation of `saveNewItem` on how you are composing the ajax request params.

Comment: @kiddorails Updated the question with ```saveNewItem``` method implementation.